# How do I identify the cryptography used in this Java framework?

Tags: java, cryptography

As described in [How do i retrieve data from a JVM renderized into a web page using C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212757/how-do-i-retrieve-data-from-a-jvm-renderized-into-a-web-page-using-c-sharp-code), I am trying to write a C# Bot to simulate queries in this website.

The problem now, is with the "Cryptography" used on the return of the webrequest for the information.

The source code for their cryptography can be found here: http://pastebin.com/fdJZvXDG

The problem is that, since the code has no comments, is there any way I can:

1. Figure out whats the `ai` parameter used for constructing the class
2. Find the Key they are using for encrypt/decrypt the information returned on the request?

Any help is appreciated here, I've read that this `DES` is a sort of Encryption pattern in Java, but I've never seen it before. Is this class implementing this pattern of only the name of the class and the pattern are the same?

Comment: You might be able to ask this on crypto.stackexchange.com, but you'll need to be able to make the question work without depending on pastebin links that may or may not be there tomorrow (if those break, this loses all context, hence highly localized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an implementation of the [DES cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard). Java has a class built in which allows you to encrypt and decrypt data with DES. [This website](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/desstring.html) shows how to use the class.

It's not a pattern, it's an open and standardized cipher.

You mentioned you want to figure out the key they are using and based on the information you have given, it simply isn't possible.

The `ai` parameter looks like it's used in the key expansion and to specify the initial key (a string) for the cipher. It seems to be a poorly implemented version and is likely incorrect; I wouldn't expect the Java classes to be able to handle this variation of the cipher.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the cipher being 56 bits you can probably break it on your home computer in ~4 hours.  According to [DES WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) "DES is now considered to be insecure for many applications. This is chiefly due to the 56-bit key size being too small; in January, 1999, distributed.net and the Electronic Frontier Foundation collaborated to publicly break a DES key in 22 hours and 15 minutes"

Your best bet is to brute force the key.

Comment: I don't even know how to start brute-forcing for reaching the key.
I will need some study